# Protect an SQLite database in an UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, entity-framework-core, .net-4.6

It is an `UWP`application using a `SQLite` database. Below, the dependencies for this application:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2",
    "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed": "1.1.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
    "Template10": "1.1.*"
    },
    // ...
}
```

The requirement is: "*[...]to have a password to access the database either from the application or any other application that can open a `SQLite` database*".

Entity Framework Core doesn't seem to support this scenario. **Any suggestion?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my [Encryption in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](http://www.bricelam.net/2016/06/13/sqlite-encryption.html) post for tips on using SQLCipher and friends with Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.

The easiest way to use it with EF Core is probably to use an open connection with your `DbContext`.

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    SqliteConnection _connection;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        _connection = new SqliteConnection(_connectionString);
        _connection.Open();

        var command = _connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "PRAGMA key = 'password';";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        options.UseSqlite(_connection);
    }

    protected override void Dispose()
    {
        _connection?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've found that the SQLite community thinks building your own is best. Then you specify the exact features and configuration you want. But [wxSQLite3](https://github.com/utelle/wxsqlite3/releases) has some binaries. (May not work on UWP)

Comment: It is really disappointing @bricelam that instead focusing in apps, that we usually create for free, protecting a bit the data we create is not possible without wasting money and time. I miss the days of SQL Compact.

Comment: I miss SQL Compact too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SQLCipher (https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher). It provides seamless full DB encryption with little overhead. It is a pain to build a VSIX for use with Visual Studio. If you do not want to build it yourself, yo can get a license from https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/.