# SQLite encryption in Universal Windows apps

Tags: sqlite, uwp, windows-store-apps

I am using SQLite database in my universal app. I want to make password protection for the DB file. I am able to set the password for the db file. But when I am trying to read it it shows error like "Sqlite26: file is encrypted or not a database file".

I referred to [this URL](http://www.bricelam.net/2016/06/13/sqlite-encryption.html). I am using Entity Framework Core in the .NET Standard library. Is it possible to read the value from the encrypted DB in .NET Standard library?

Comment: UWP app target version is 16299. Dotnet standard library version is 2.0. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite(2.0.1).Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools(2.0.1)

Comment: Did you mean you encryption with `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core`, and reading data using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`? Could you please provide more code snippet about how you encrypt?

Answer (score 0):

The author of the article you linked actually has an [answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764246/protect-an-sqlite-database-in-an-uwp-app) that deals with the EF Core scenario as well. You can open the database with EF Core in the `OnConfiguring` method override:

```
class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    private SqliteConnection _connection;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        _connection = new SqliteConnection(_connectionString);
        _connection.Open();

        var command = _connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "PRAGMA key = 'password';";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        options.UseSqlite(_connection);
    }

    protected override void Dispose()
    {
        _connection?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The kez is to provide the password as in a `PRAGMA` command before the first query on the connection.

Comment: This approach throws exception as "Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException:SQLite Error 26:'file is encrypted or is not a database'